# Tiger VNC on Centos 6.3 fails, font catalog not properly configured

Tags: linux, centos, vnc

I'm trying to set up [Tiger VNC](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tigervnc/index.php?title=Welcome_to_TigerVNC) server on CentOS 6.3 but I'm getting the following error message when I run the command `vncserver`:

> WARNING: The first attempt to start Xvnc failed, possibly because the font
>       catalog is not properly configured.  Attempting to determine an appropriate
>       font path for this system and restart Xvnc using that font path ...
>       Could not start Xvnc.
>
> /usr/bin/Xvnc: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/Xvnc: undefined symbol: pixman_composite_trapezoids
>   /usr/bin/Xvnc: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/Xvnc: undefined symbol: pixman_composite_trapezoids

Answer (score 7):

So we managed to resolve this by just updating everything on the system:

```
yum update
```

I would love to know what was updated that got it working, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far. Hope this helps!

EDIT: OK, I figured out what needs to be updated, go ahead and update these 3 packages:

```
yum install pixman pixman-devel libXfont
```

That should do it!